# How to find from within a csh script whether a certain command is available?

Tags: csh, tcsh

In a csh script, I need to perform something only if a certain command is available. I wanted to do something like

```
if( _WHAT_TO_PUT_HERE_ ) then   # enter only if command "cmd" is in the path
   cmd ...
endif
```

how to do that in csh or tcsh?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script

Comment: @David I had a look, but on my tcsh neither `command`, `hash` nor `type` are available :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess using the where command will solve your issue

Check this:

```
~/animesh >where grep
/bin/grep
/tools/cfr/bin/grep
~/animesh >where egrep
/bin/egrep
/tools/cfr/bin/egrep
~/animesh >where xgrep
~/animesh >
```

so lets say you are trying to find a command named my_cmd
try the following code:

```
if(`where my_cmd` != "") then
   my_cmd
endif
```