# csh script: check if command exists

Tags: command, where-clause, csh

I would like to have something like this

`if (command_not_exists) exit`

Can someone tell me how to achieve this functionality in a *cshell* script?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In other languages there is a function try to do so, maybe in csh there is something similar...

Comment: My problem is solved using the solution at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137577/how-to-find-from-within-a-csh-script-whether-a-certain-command-is-available?rq=1) : if(`where test_cmd` == "") then echo " test_cmd: Command not found "; exit(1); endif     thanks @Llopis

Comment: If it is solved then answer your own question and accept it to close the question. So other people know how to do so, and  prevent others to search a solution for this question :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My problem is solved using `where` command (I was trying with `which` command). Solution:

```
   if(`where test_cmd` == "") then
      printf "\ntest_cmd: Command not found\n";
      exit(1);
   endif
```

Thanks

Comment: In case `tcsh` is the shell and the variable `printexitvalue` is set it does not work because `where test_cmd` evaluates to `Exit 1` if `test_cmd` does not exist.  I.e. in shell scripts you want to unset `printexitvalue` first.

Comment: `where` does not exist for me (`csh` version `20110502-3ubuntu0.18.04.1`).